# Insert comment into expression language

Tags: jsp, el

Is anything like this possible?

```
${ long_boolean_expression_a <comment here>
|| long_boolean_expression_b <comment here>
|| long_boolean_expression_c <comment here>}
```

?

Comment: The fact that you have such a long expression and a need to comment is a good sign that your view does things that should be done, in Java, by your model or your controller.

Comment: Just not possible or overcomplicated in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK There is no such provision to add comments inside EL.

Comment: So it seems. Yet anther annoyance :)